# mongodb aggregation for 2 topmost arrays with counts

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have been struggling with this for hours, and I'm sure this will be easy for some of you out there.

I have a collection with 2 topmost arrays:

```
{
    ...,
    topmost1: ["abc", "xyz"],
    topmost2: ["123","456"],
    ...
},
{
    ...,
    topmost1: ["abc", "lmo"],
    topmost2: ["987","654"],
    ...
}
```

I got this no problem: unwind one sum into a count, check for multiples then sort from most at the top to least at the bottom.  But I'm having trouble with the compounds $groups and/or $unwinds.  Here's the pipeline for one.

```
[
 { '$unwind' : '$topmost1' },
 { '$group' : { '_id' : '$topmost1', 'count': { '$sum':1 } } },
 { '$match' : { 'count' : { '$gt': 1 } } },
 { '$sort' : { 'count' : -1 } }
]
```

The end result should show look something like this from above data:

```
{ [ { '_id' : 'abc', 'count' : 56, 'topmost2' : ['123', '456', '987', '654'] }, ...]
```

Sorted on count of instances of topmost1 (count), and only include documents where there are more than one topmost2.  FYI one field is MACs and one is Hostnames, so they do not match between the arrays.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you mean topmost1 and topmost2 can have same value e.g. abc and you want to count the values and sort in descending order?

Comment: I edited the post to be more clear and added sample output.